# Is it worth to use latest versions of PHP and related frameworks?

Tags: php

I have to maintain a website written in PHP running on version **5.3.22**, smarty **2.6.19**. The whole site is divided into two dependent subsites (one for the world and second one as CMS site for admin).

The company which developed this solution took the easy way out, just delivering already built product after few modifications. I'm on my way to merging everything into one suited piece.

My question is: is it worth to merge everything to native PHP, leaving Smarty convention, deliberately not using any of modern framework etc.? Is it worth to keep developing my own class for generating HTML (eg. `createTag('th',attributes,value)`)? What are the benefits of using newest versions of PHP, Smarty and so on?

Comment: "deliberately not using any of modern framework etc" --- do you have that much free time that you want to waste?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel...  I haven't used Smarty, but from using Cake PHP I would say ABSOLUTELY to using template!  As soon as projects get more complex the templates save you so much time implementing things such as logins, security, etc...  Also, a good MVC framework is generally very customisable, so if they don't have what you want you can add it on :)

Comment: This question is open to a lot of differences in opinion and isn't a clear technical question so I don't think StackOverflow is the best place for it, but anyway I agree with the others that trying to implement this on your own without a framework will cost you far more time than it would save. Things that seem simple to implement yourself on the surface usually end up being far more complicated.

Comment: As to the version of PHP, that matters less unless the framework you choose requires a newer version, or unless you need a new feature like traits - so probably not.

Comment: @Matt Browne: "so probably not" --- versions after 5.3 have been *significantly improved* (from performance point of view)

Comment: @zerkms fair point, and newer versions are more secure too

Comment: OP what is meant by "native PHP"?? You mean you you think something smarty is not native PHP??? Or do you just not want to use it and make your own template system? You say is it worth it but you didnt say why do you want to do this?

Comment: To be precise: in my question I've accented that the solution I'm working on is a bunch of websites (at least two). This sites came from prototypes (because the company who developed it, is producing such sites massively. I mean that when you see the construction of the code, dependences, variable naming etc you will discover that this cames from other site or maybe some prototype, which is heavily customised to fulfill customer needs). So I had put myself a target to combine those pages in a matter of performance, readability and unity. That's why I wanted to bring everything to native...

Comment: @Brandin: Smarty is written in PHP, in a sake of compliance with PHP I suppose. But it uses some sophisticated methods to provide separation of presentation layer, the second argument which rise the authors of it is performance (caching and so on). I don't really understand how could this be achieved. It's really a combination of two really opposite arguments. Marginal readability with performance boost. So thats why I wanted to write some simple factorial class with static functions to fully control the balance between readability and performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommend to update software whenever there is an update available. The same goes for php, smarty and so on but whenever updating php, smarty or any other programming / scripting language have in mind you possibly have to refactor sourcecode - think twice.

Template engines such as smarty are very useful as they strictly divide business logic and the view.

The third point you mentioned are frameworks. As Kvothe mentioned already "Don't reinvent the wheel". That's why a lot of php frameworks exists in the www. Each has it advantages and disadvantages - I recommend to test some and choose the one you like most.